# Segment a txt file column to lists

Tags: python, list

I am have text file with multiple columns and separated by commas.

I am trying to read it and put each column into it's own separate list but I can't seem to do it.

What I've done so far:

```
with open(file, 'r') as file_test:
    file_lines = file_test.readlines()
    file_strip = [line.strip("\n") for line in file_lines]

#I've split big list into separate lists within `file_strip`
    file_columns= [file_strip [i:i + 1] for i in range(0, len(file_strip ), 1)][2:]
```

So now my data is as follows:

```
[['22AUG18 000000, 22AUG18 000149, 5.722, UOS2'], ['22JUL18 012703, 22JUL18 013810, 52.2811, UOS2']]
```

I don't know how to get rid of the ' in the beginning and end of each list too

I want the first element in each list to be in `List1`, 2nd element in each list to be in `List2` etc...

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the `csv` module? It was designed to do what you want to do!

```
import csv

with open(file, 'r') as file_test:
    csv_test = csv.reader(file_test)
    for row in csv_test:
         print(row)
```

Will print

```
['22AUG18 000000', '22AUG18 000149', '5.722', 'UOS2']
['22JUL18 012703', '22JUL18 013810', '52.2811', 'UOS2']
```

If you want to separate that in lists you can zip() it:

```
with open(file, 'r') as file_test:
    csv_test = csv.reader(file_test)
    list1, list2, list3, list4 = zip(*csv_test)
```

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse.. havent used Python in a long time, forgot about this library. Thanks. Will accept as answer